# Error autenticación con cuenta de google en android

Tags: android

tengo un problema al momento de utilizar el login de google en android me sale este error:

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
                                     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2694)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2159)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6351)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6122)
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3994)
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
                                         at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2694) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2159) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6351) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6122) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3994) 
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

esta es me activity de inicio de sesion:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


@VisibleForTesting
public ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio_sesion);



    // Button listeners
    findViewById(R.id.sesion).setOnClickListener(this);


    // [START config_signin]
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END config_signin]

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]
}

// [START on_start_check_user]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}
// [END on_start_check_user]

// [START onactivityresult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
// [END onactivityresult]

// [START auth_with_google]
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.sesion), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_google]

// [START signin]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signin]

private void signOut() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google sign out
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    // Firebase sign out
    mAuth.signOut();

    // Google revoke access
    mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess().addOnCompleteListener(this,
            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            });
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    hideProgressDialog();
    if (user != null) {

    } else {

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.sesion) {
        signIn();
    }
}



public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("cargando");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    hideProgressDialog();
  }
}
```

De antemano agradezco si me pueden orientar.

Comment: como generaste el id R.string.default_web_client_id?

Comment: el que firebase auto genera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, la verdad era algo muy simple, tenia en el manifest "android:noHistory=true" esto provocaba que al momento de abrir la ventana para seleccionar la cuenta de google, la activity se cerraba y esto generaba los errores, esto sucedía si la api era inferior a 25, comparto esto por si a alguien le llega a suceder.